# Как перекрыть одну картинку другой картинкой через псевдоэлемент?

Tags: css

Есть основная картинка и есть декоративный элемент который нужно расположить под картинкой но что бы он немного выглядывал из под нее

основную картинку я вставил в `div` и уже этому классу задал псевдоэлемент с другой картинкой проблема в том что почему то не срабатывает `z-index` при любых раскладах элемент заданный через псевдокласс остается выше

```css
.ourvision__img {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    width: 48px;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.ourvision__img::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 35px;
    background: blue;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ourvision__img"></div>
```

Comment: если у элемента z-index не трогать, а у after поставить -1, то работает

Comment: Спасибо !!!!)))